# how to get count of all followings till 2016-03-20 fom twitter api

Tags: api, twitter

i am using following code but this code give me the total count of tweet, followings and followers but now i want to get all followings till given date like till 2016-03-20.
how is this possible for me to get all followings till given date.

```
$connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, $access_token['oauth_token'], $access_token['oauth_token_secret']);

$user = $connection->get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json?screen_name=" . $twitteruser);

$following = intval($user->friends_count);
$followers = intval($user->followers_count);
$tweets = intval($user->statuses_count);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot.  The date that a following occured is not exposed via the API.

If it ever were, I'd expect it to be in https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/friendships/lookup